# How to make panels visible when we select values from DropDown filter in Sentinel Workbook?

Tags: excel, kql

I would like to make items conditionally visible in an azure workbook.

The visibility depends on the items that I choose from a dropdown parameter. I managed to achieve this by means of a single selection, the problem is that I would like to make it work also with multiple selections.

This guide describes in general what I am talking about: [workbooks interactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-configurations)

Any hint?

Tried with using parameters inside condition.